# Documentation about "left-offset" syntax?

Tags: spark-view-engine

Where do I find more documentation about the [left-offset syntax](https://github.com/SparkViewEngine/spark) in spark?

Specifically is there an [elements reference](https://github.com/SparkViewEngine/spark/wiki/Elements-Reference) for "left-offset" syntax?

EDIT:
The syntax seems to be like [pug](https://github.com/pugjs/pug)(formerly known as jade).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only documentation exists [in the github repo](https://github.com/SparkViewEngine/spark/wiki/Jade-Haml-like-syntax-support), and yes you're right, the files are suffixed with `.shade` because it used the `jade` syntax as inspiration. You should be able to figure a lot of it out from there and by looking at some example of its usage:

- https://gist.github.com/loudej/2371061
- https://github.com/loudej/sake/tree/master/src/Sake.Library/Shared